# Форматирование кода в Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, форматирование

Здравствуйте. Как сделать (и вообще возможно ли) чтоб код в Эклипсе был отформатирован как в Notepade++? Там условия if...else, методы вот такого вида:

```
     @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 .   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 .    setContentView(R.layout.main);
 .
 .
 .
 }
```

Или

```
    if () {
    .
    .
    .
    }else{
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

Comment: Для какого языка программирования? Android?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для форматирования существует сочетание клавиш <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

В коде:

1. Ctrl+A
2. Ctrl+I

PS 
Для настройки форматирования :

Windows -> Preferences , а потом Java -> Code Style -> Formatter

Comment: А какой именно форматтер? У меня по умолчанию 3 и такого нет

Comment: У меня по умолчанию стоит Eclipse [built-in], если нажмете кнопочку Edit... , то сможете поменять практически любые настройки форматирования.

Comment: Пробовал через Windows -> Preferences , а потом Java -> Code Style -> Formatter, но там много всего не понятного